# How do I display a List of items inside a tooltip?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following style applied to buttons in my application

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonPartChooserValidation" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ControlBaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="(Validation.Errors)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}">
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <converters:ValidationErrorsToBackgroundColorConverter/>
                </Binding.Converter>
            </Binding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors).[0].ErrorContent.Value[0], RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">                    
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Acceptable value"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When there is a validation error the button gets a yellow background and a tooltip displays the first item in the list of errors.  The yellow background is what I am trying to achieve, but I would like to display the full list of validation errors and not just the first one.  I have tried the following and just gotten an empty list displayed (just the Trigger from above for brevity, names match).

```
<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding (Validation.Errors).[0].ErrorContent.Value, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding ErrMsg}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

I would almost certainly need two ListBox elements to display each of the lists in my object, but as of now I can't even get one to work.  What am I setting up wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind to the Validation.Errors attached property of the PlacementTarget of the Tooltip:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ToolTip>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.(Validation.Errors), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToolTip}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ToolTip>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: In my case  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent.Value[0]}" /> works a little better.